# Couldn't find class template in visual studio web api project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I couldn't find a class template in visual studio asp.net core web api project ,
when clicking :

=> Add
=> Class

[image]

[image: Class option doesn't show]

Comment: [That could help you](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b75f659-521e-4e08-b093-11d7bfb63ef1/missing-web-templates-for-c-in-visual-studio-2015?forum=netfxsetup)

Answer (score 2):

So the problem was the ASPNET and web development installation.

Simply go to 'Visual Studio Installer' > Click on 'Modify' for your Visual Studio.
*(Visual Studio Installer is a separate application with Visual Studio)*

[image]